# time zone formatting not accept Z pattern in scala

Tags: java, scala

I have dates come with this fromate :

```
20170629001322+2400
20170629001322+0000
```

and I need to parse it , the first one failed to parse while the second one success , below what i try in scala code

```
scala> import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.ParseException

scala> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

scala> import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Date

scala> import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Locale

scala> import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.TimeZone
    
var sdf : SimpleDateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssZ", Locale.ENGLISH)
scala> sdf.parse("20170629001322+0000")
res2: java.util.Date = Thu Jun 29 01:13:22 WAT 2017

scala> sdf.parse("20170629001322+2400")
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20170629001322+2400"
  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
  ... 32 elided
```

I also try to replace z by x but still not able to parse , any help ?

Comment: If you use the `java.time` library instead of the old and outdated `SimpleDate`, you'll get a better, more descriptive, error. A timezone offset of `2400` results in a `Value out of range` error. There is no timezone 24 hours off from UTC.

Comment: +24 is not a valid timezone